# Cannot resolve method get() when using the Picasso library

Tags: java, picasso

When I try to use the Picasso library, I get an error saying "cannot resolve method get()". What might be the cause of this?

I've tried some solutions based on answers given on this type of question here on stack Overflow, but it didn't solve my problem.

Here is my dependency:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Here is my Java code that throws the error "cannot resolve method get()":

```java
Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(targetImage);
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve the error by changing the Picasso library version from:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this answer may help of someone,
I had the same issue to resolve it instead of using this using .get()

```
Picasso.get().load(imageURL).into(imageView);
```

I used it using .with()

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).into(imageView);
```